# Angular 4 ngx-rocket deep link routing issue

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, yeoman-generator

I've successfully setup routes for some pages in my Angular 4 app using the ngx-rocket yeoman generator. For example I created a page called 'eat' and when you go to my home page at www.haakon.io and then click the eat link you are taken to that page. If you try to type that link into the browser, for example http://www.haakon.io/eat and try to navigate there you get the 404 error page. I know this has to do with deep linking issues but I have tried some of the angular 1.5 solutions and they don't work. Specifically I have the base href set in my index.html page:

```
  <base href="/"/>
```

Here is my app-routing.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  // Fallback when no prior route is matched
  { path: '**', redirectTo: '', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Here is my route.service.ts:

```
import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { ShellComponent } from './shell/shell.component';

/**
 * Provides helper methods to create routes.
 */
export class Route {

  /**
   * Creates routes using the shell component and authentication.
   * @param routes The routes to add.
   * @return {Routes} The new routes using shell as the base.
   */
  static withShell(routes: Routes): Routes {
    return [{
      path: '',
      component: ShellComponent,
      children: routes
    }];
  }

}
```

And finally my eat-routing.module.ts:

```
import { Route } from '../core/route.service';
import { extract } from '../core/i18n.service';
import { EatComponent } from './eat.component';

const routes: Routes = Route.withShell([
  { path: 'eat', component: EatComponent, data: { title: extract('Eat') } }
]);

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forChild(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class EatRoutingModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

After more investigation it turned out that a file was deleted off the server and affected the default routing on the server level.

Initially I thought of just deleting this issue but decided to post the answer in case it helps someone.

The solution was to create a .htaccess file with the following contents and placing it at your root folder on your host:

```
# If the request is a file, folder or symlink that exists, serve it up
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ - [S=1]

# otherwise, serve your index.html app
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.html
```

Now www.haakon.io/art is accessible by typing it directly into a browser or linking from another website.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit old, but there is also a way to make your angular app use hash style routing instead of url routes if you're not able to modify the .htaccess. The URLs it uses aren't as conventional...

www.haakon.io/#/art

but they bypass most server configs that might cause issues like you ran into.

To use it just add it to your router module import like this...

RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {useHash: true})

I had to use this recently on a project because it was a UI for a service running a simple http server that would interpret everything after the / as a physical file/folder and did not have an .htaccess. Using the hash format was the only way to not confuse the server if the user reloaded the browser manually and the URL was anything other then the default URL.